# Why is there an error during build next.js project?

Tags: javascript, next.js, build

**my node.js.yml file
**

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build
    - run: npm run export
    
    - name: Deploy 
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
      with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: out # The folder the action should deploy.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toRBr.png)
**error here**

link to my repository
https://github.com/EduardKop/web-cv-next

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  distDir: 'build',
  images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '',
  }
  
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

i wrote next.config.js config. I made a commit, then set up the action as indicated above in the yaml file and got an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the path of images, in error says that path can't be less that 0 char.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  distDir: 'build',
  images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '',
  }
  
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

You should write path in **path** attribute.

Comment: understood, and what path should I write? Can you suggest

Comment: Probably that want a folder from which that will take pics